# Ошибка при прерывании программы(Ctrl+C)

Tags: python, python-3.x

При прерывании программы(Ctrl+C) в PyCharm выходит выходит ошибка
Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AlexTrask\Desktop\think\Python3_AutoClicker\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\AlexTrask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1458, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

код

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

Подскажите как от этого избавится может что то установлено не так? нормально ли это вообще?

Comment: Это не ошибка, KeyboardInterrupt - это исключение прерывания программы через Ctrl-C

Comment: Алексей, вопрос из любопытства - не риторический. А почему было не набрать KeyboardInterrupt 
 в Google? Первая же ссылка: <https://pythonz.net/references/named/keyboardinterrupt/>

Answer (score 2):

Оно так и должно быть! KeyboardInterrupt - исключение, вызываемое при нажатии Ctrl+C